# Implemeting Shunting yard with Logic

Tags: java, enums, case, discrete-mathematics, shunting-yard

So I am trying to implement a shunting yard to work with Logic, I thought it was going to be easy, until I ran into the problem of setting a precedence for the material conditional(->) and bi-conditional(<->) statements since they need to be represented as String and not char. I need to be able to read a file with a statement such as `(A|B) -> !C`(which means:(A OR B) implies NOT C) and translate it into postfix notation. I keep getting a NullPointerException on line 115 and I am actually not sure why, can I only set a case using char values? Or do I need to find another method of setting precedence for symbols. Here is my code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.Reader;

public class ShuntingYard
{

public static ArrayList<String> symbols = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> letters = new ArrayList<String>();
public static String path = "";
public static void main(String args[])
{
    ShuntingYard sy = new ShuntingYard();

    //Scans in File.
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String prompt = "Please specify the file path.\n Use the form: D:\\DiscreteMath\\inputFile.txt";
    System.out.println(prompt);
    path = scan.next();
    File file = new File(path);
    String infix = "";

    try{

        scan = new Scanner(file);
        infix = scan.nextLine();

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println(" No file");
    }
    // calls postfix function
    String postfix = sy.postfix(infix);
    System.out.println("\nPostfix expression : " + postfix);
    String al = "A,B,C,D,E,";

}
public enum Precedence 
{
    //configure precedence of symbols and operands.
    lparen(0), rparen(1), not(2), and(3), or(4), mc(5), bc(6), eos(7), operand(8);

    private int index;
    Precedence(int index)
    {
        this.index = index;
    }
    public int getIndex()
    {
        return index;
    }
}
private static final int[] isp = {0,19,12,12,13,13,0};
private static final int[] icp = {20,19,12,12,13,13,0};
private static final String[] operators = {"{","}","!","&","|","->","<->"," "};

//initializes stack
private Precedence[] stack;

private int top;

private Precedence pop()
{
    return stack[top--];
}
private void push(Precedence ele)
{
    stack[++top] = ele;
}
//Sets Precedence of symbols.
public Precedence getToken(String symbol)
{
    switch(symbol)
    {
        case "(" : return Precedence.lparen;
        case ")" : return Precedence.rparen;
        case "!" : return Precedence.not;
        case "&" : return Precedence.and;
        case "|" : return Precedence.or;
        case "->" : return Precedence.mc;
        case "<->" : return Precedence.bc;
        case " " : return Precedence.eos;
        default : return Precedence.operand;
    }
}
//Changes infix to postfix notation then returns a string value.
public String postfix(String infix)
{
    String postfix = ""; 
    top = 0;
    stack = new Precedence[infix.length()];
    Precedence token;
    for(int i = 0; i<infix.length(); i++)
    {
        token = getToken(Character.toString(infix.charAt(i)));

        if(token == Precedence.operand)
        {
            postfix = postfix + infix.charAt(i);
        }
        else if(token == Precedence.rparen)
        {
            while(stack[top] != Precedence.lparen)
            {
                postfix = postfix + operators[pop().getIndex()];
            }
            pop();
        }
        else
        {
            while(isp[stack[top].getIndex()] >= icp[token.getIndex()])
            {
                postfix = postfix + operators[pop().getIndex()];
            }
            push(token);
        }
    }
    while((token = pop()) != Precedence.eos)
    {
        postfix = postfix + operators[token.getIndex()];
    }
    return postfix;
}
```

}

Comment: Running through a debugger the error is easy to track. In the first run through the postfix method, it reads the first token which is a Precedence.lparen, its not an operand or rparen hence it goes to the else block. At this point the stack is empty filled with null giving your null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not checking for an empty stack. If you add a check for empty stacks in two places the code can work.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ShuntingYard
{

public static ArrayList<String> symbols = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> letters = new ArrayList<String>();
public static String path = "";
public static void main(String args[])
{
    ShuntingYard sy = new ShuntingYard();

    //Scans in File.
//    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
//    String prompt = "Please specify the file path.\n Use the form: D:\\DiscreteMath\\inputFile.txt";
//    System.out.println(prompt);
//    path = scan.next();
//    File file = new File(path);
    String infix = "(A|B)&C"; //    String infix = "(A|B) -> !C";

//    try{
//
//        scan = new Scanner(file);
//        infix = scan.nextLine();
//
//    }
//    catch(IOException e)
//    {
//        System.err.println(" No file");
//    }
    // calls postfix function
    String postfix = sy.postfix(infix);
    System.out.println("\nPostfix expression : " + postfix);
    String al = "A,B,C,D,E,";
    // line 38
}
public enum Precedence 
{
    //configure precedence of symbols and operands.
    lparen(0), rparen(1), not(2), and(3), or(4), mc(5), bc(6), eos(7), operand(8);

    private int index;
    Precedence(int index)
    {
        this.index = index;
    }
    public int getIndex()
    {
        return index;
    }
}
private static final int[] isp = {0,19,12,12,13,13,0};
private static final int[] icp = {20,19,12,12,13,13,0};
private static final String[] operators = {"{","}","!","&","|","->","<->"," "};

//initializes stack
private Precedence[] stack;

private int top;

private Precedence pop()
{
    return stack[top--];
}
private void push(Precedence ele)
{
    stack[++top] = ele;
}
//Sets Precedence of symbols.
public Precedence getToken(String symbol)
{
    switch(symbol)
    {
        case "(" : return Precedence.lparen;
        case ")" : return Precedence.rparen;
        case "!" : return Precedence.not;
        case "&" : return Precedence.and;
        case "|" : return Precedence.or;
        case "->" : return Precedence.mc;
        case "<->" : return Precedence.bc;
        case " " : return Precedence.eos;
        default : return Precedence.operand;
    }
}
//Changes infix to postfix notation then returns a string value.
public String postfix(String infix)
{
    String postfix = ""; 
    top = -1;
    stack = new Precedence[infix.length()];
    Precedence token;
    for(int i = 0; i<infix.length(); i++)
    {
        token = getToken(Character.toString(infix.charAt(i)));
        System.out.println("Token "+ infix.charAt(i) + " " + token);
        if(token == Precedence.operand)
        {
            postfix = postfix + infix.charAt(i);
        }
        else if(token == Precedence.rparen)
        {
            while(stack[top] != Precedence.lparen)
            {
                postfix = postfix + operators[pop().getIndex()];
            }
            pop();
        }
        else
        {
            while(top>=0 && isp[stack[top].getIndex()] >= icp[token.getIndex()])
            {
                postfix = postfix + operators[pop().getIndex()];
            }
            push(token);
        } System.out.println("Postfix '"+postfix+"' Stack "+Arrays.deepToString(stack));
    }
    while(top>=0 && (  (token = pop()) != Precedence.eos) )
    {
        postfix = postfix + operators[token.getIndex()];
    }
    return postfix;
}
}
```

I've added some debugging print statements to help see whats going on.

The code does not work with two character operators like ->

Also use a java.util.Deque for the stack

```
Deque<Precedence> stack = new ArrayDeque<Precedence>();
```

which provide the standard interface for a stack.